# Programatically tell Chrome to fast forward 10 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

We are using a headless Chrome to take screenshots of our websites. Because on startup there are some animations we set a timeout of 10 seconds before we take the screenshot. We are running all of this on an AWS lambda. It sucks though that we actually have to wait 10 *real life* seconds. Is there a way to tell (headless) Chrome to fast forward (or "fake") 10 seconds?

Comment: Well since there's a timeout your best bet is executing some JS to do this.

Comment: We are using a timeout to wait for animations. The animations could be implemented using CSS animations / transitions.

Comment: As I said, you'll probably have to write some JS to override that time out since there isn't really a speed-up thingy (that I'm aware of) in Chrome (headless or not) unless you use something like cheat engine. (which would probably break it). Meaning to "Fake" 10 seconds you'll have to manipulate the website itself most likely (JS) since manipulating the browser itself is going to be harder and requires more skill.